# Proof of Lebesgue criterion in Analysis 2 by Zorich

Tags: analysis, riemann-integration

In the book "Analysis 2" by Vladimir Zorich, the author gives a proof of Lebesgue criterion for integrability. Later in *Remark 2* on page 144 the following is stated:

*"Since the Cauchy criterion for existence of a limit is valid in any complete metric space, the sufficiency (but not the necessity part), as the proof shows, holds for functions in any complete normed vector space"*

I have worked through the proof that is given thoroughly, and I understand it well. One thing I can't seem to pinpoint is *"but not the necessity part"*. In the proof I can not find anything that would fail in an arbitrary Banach space. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is isomorphic to any n-dimensional normed vector space I assume that the proof doesn't necessarily hold for infinite dimensional spaces. Note that I am aware that some points in the proof require further explaining (such as the $1/2n_0$ inequality).

Here is the proof given in the book:

Let $f:I\to \mathbb R$ where $I$ is an n-dimensional interval.

*Necessity*: It is already known that $f\in \mathcal{R}(I)$ implies that $f$ is bounded. Suppose $|f|\leq M$ for some $M\geq 0$.

We shall now verify that $f$ is continous at almost all points of $I$. To do this, we shall show that if the set $E$ of its points of discontinuity does not have measure zero, then $f \notin \mathcal{R}(I)$.

Indeed, representing $E$ in the form $E = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ where $E_n=\{x\in I | \omega(f;x)\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$, we conclude that if $E$ does not have measure zero, then there exists an index $n_0$ such that $E_{n_0}$ is also not a set of measure zero (It is known that a countable union of sets of measure zero is of measure zero). Let $P$ be an arbitrary partition of the interval $I$ into intervals $\{I_i\}$. We break partition $P$ into two groups of intervals $A$ and $B$, where
$$
A = \bigg{\{} I_i \in P \bigg| I_i \cap E_{n_0} \neq \emptyset \land \omega(f, I_i) \geq \frac{1}{2n_0} \bigg{\}}; B=P\backslash A
$$

The system of intervals $A$ froms a covering of set $E_{n_0}$. In fact, each point of $E_{n_0}$ lies either in the interior of some interval $I_i \in P$ (Because the oscillation at an interior point of a set $S$ is always less that or equal to the oscillation over the entire set $S$), in which case obviously $I_i \in A$, or on the boundary of several intervals of the partition $P$ (This required a little explanation, but doesn't seem to fail for infinite-dimensional spaces). In the latter case, the oscillation of the function must be at least $\frac{1}{2n_0}$ on at least one of these intervals (because of the triangle inequality), and that interval belongs to the system $A$.

We shall now show that by choosing the set $\xi$ of distinguished points in the intervals of the partition $P$ in different ways we can change the value of the Riemann sum significantly.

To be specific, we chose the sets of points $\xi ^\prime$ and $\xi ^{\prime\prime}$ such that in the intervals of the system $B$ the distinguished points are the same, while in the intervals $I_i$ of the system $A$, we choose the points $\xi_i^\prime$ and $\xi_i ^{\prime\prime}$ so that $f(\xi_i^\prime) - f(\xi_i^{\prime \prime}) > \frac{1}{3n_0}$. We then have

$$
|\sigma(f,P,\xi^\prime) - \sigma(f,P,\xi^{\prime \prime})| = \bigg|\sum_{I_i\in A}(f(\xi_i^\prime) - f(\xi_i^{\prime \prime}))|I_i|\bigg| > \frac{1}{3n_0} \sum_{I_i \in A}|I_i| > c > 0
$$

The existence of such a constant c follows from the fact that the intervals of the system $A$ from a covering of the set $E_{n_0}$, which by hypothesis is not a set of measure zero.

Since $P$ was an arbitrary partition of the interval I, we conclude from the Cauchy criterion that the Riemann sums $\sigma(f,P,\xi)$ cannot have a limit as $\lambda (P) \to 0$, that is $f\notin \mathcal {R}. \Box$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with summing large number of discontinuties to one large enough. In $\mathbb R$, we have that if $|x_{i, 0} - x_{i, 1}| \geq 1$ for all $i$, we can find $\alpha_i \in \{0, 1\}$ s.t. $|\sum_{i = 1}^n t_i \cdot (x_{i, \alpha_i} - x_{i, 1 - \alpha_i})| \geq \sum_{i=1}^n t_i$.

Similarly, for finite-dimension spaces, if $\|x_{i, 0} - x_{i, 1}\| \geq 1$, for some $\alpha_i$ we have $\|\sum_{i = 1}^n t_i \cdot (x_{i, \alpha_i} - x_{i, 1 - \alpha_i})\| \geq c \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n t_i$ (where $c$ depends on space, but is positive).

In infinite-dimension case, it's no longer the case. For example, in $c_0$, $x_{i, 0} = 0$, $x_{i, 1} = e_i$, for any choice of $\alpha$, we will get $\sum_{i=1}^n t_i \cdot (x_{i, \alpha_i} - x_{i, 1 - \alpha_i}) = (\pm t_1, \pm t_2, \ldots, \pm t_n, \ldots)$ and thus norm of this sum is at most $\max t_i$.

This sequence can be used to make a Riemann-integrable function discontinuous everywhere. Let $q_i$ be any enumeration of rational points in $[0, 1]$ and define
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} e_i, x = q_i\\ 0, x \notin \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$

For any partition of $[0, 1]$ with mesh less than $\varepsilon$ and any choice of points, we will have all coordinates of Riemann sum have absoulute value of at most $\varepsilon$, so $f$ is Riemann integrable with integral $0$.

Comment: I see your point. But the codomain of my function is the set of real numbers, and the domain is supposed to be an interval in a normed vector space and not the other way around.

Comment: In Russian version, remark 2 says "... holds for functions *with values* in any complete normed vector space" (bold my - mihaild). How do you define Riemann integral for function with infinite-dimension domain?

Comment: *it's difficult to define Riemann integral on Banach space because there is no analogue of Lebesgue measure (and also it's not clear how to define partition to finite number of pieces using coordinates)

Comment: Wow, I haven't tought of it that way. Thank you! :)